# Effective creation of the multiple buttons in JavaFX

Tags: lambda, uibutton, javafx-8, java-stream, actionevent

I'm tying to build a Pane on my GUI containing aprox 12 separate buttons, each havin a distinct name, text and ActionEvent reaction. This is the pattern for each button:

```
    Button compB = new Button();
    compB.setText("BtnText");
    compB.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            System.out.println("ADD_INPUT_LINK");
        }
    });
```

I was wondering if there is a way to use a stream (or mutiple streams for that matter) in order to assign to each button a distinct name, text and ActionEvent.
Maybe with 3 different streams with elements having an identifiable int that I could use for binding?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you are reading these streams from file or some other source and can init buttons in a loop you wouldn't benefit from using them.

If you just want to have shorter code you can use factory method. Something like this:

```
public class Buttons extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        VBox root = new VBox();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

        doButton(root, "hi", ()->{System.out.println("hi");});
        doButton(root, "hoi", ()->{System.out.println("1");});
        doButton(root, "hei", ()->{System.out.println("2");});
        doButton(root, "hai", ()->{System.out.println("3");});
        doButton(root, "hio", ()->{System.out.println("4");});

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static Button doButton(Pane owner, String name, final Runnable handler) {
        Button compB = new Button();
        compB.setText(name);
        compB.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                handler.run();
            }
        });
        owner.getChildren().add(compB);
        return compB;
    }
}
```